# How to use the hover() to style multiple specific elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-hover

I'm trying to achieve a `hover()` function where when one `<a>` tag is hovered, it will also style all of the other `<a>` tags within that `<tr>` tag. I want to make it in sync with each other when either one of the `<a>` tag in the table is hovered, they will all be in sync with the style in the given table row.

Here's the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/73483/

Attempted this code using `closest()` and `parent()` methods, but it doesn't work:

**JS:**

```
$('#table-dropdown a').hover(function(){
    //$(this).parent().siblings('a').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('a:not(.link)').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    //$(this).parent().siblings('a').css('color', 'red !important');
    $(this).closest('tr').siblings('a:not(.link)').css('color', 'red !important');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="table-dropdown" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:initial; border-image:initial; border-width:1px; width:657px">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:64px">
                <p><strong>Abbr</strong></p>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:585px">
                <p><strong>Title</strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:64px">
                <a class="AAA" href="#">AAA</a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:585px">
                <a class="AAA" href="#">Heading 1</a>
                <a class="link AAA" href="#"><span class="arrow"></span></a>

                <p id="AAA" style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION - Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:64px">
                <a href="#">BBB</a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:585px">
                <a href="#">Heading 2</a>

            <p id="BBB" style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION - Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:64px">
                <a href="#">CCC</a>
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align:top; width:585px">
                <a href="#">Heading 3</a>

            <p id="CCC" style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION - Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: The `<tr>` elements don't have any siblings which are `<a>` tags, so your event handler is doing nothing. I think you mean that `siblings` to be `find` (which will find all `<a>` tags which are descendants).

Comment: Why are you limiting yourself to using document events (hover) instead of just pure CSS?  In this case, javascript simply adds to the problem because you have code depending on document selectors (css) depending on DOM elements.  Using CSS, at the very least, if your javascript breaks your page would still be styled.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Because css selectors do not have previous sibling selectors and in this case, some of the `<a>` tags aren't siblings and are in separate `<td>` tags and therefore, one will be hovered but the others will not. I also want to avoid using specific class names because I need something dynamic to work.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Thank you. I didn't know why I didn't think of that. Slight problem. When I hover out, the style are stuck with it. I want remove those styles when hovered out as well.

Comment: @TheAmazingKnight that's because jQuery's `hover` actually takes *two* function callbacks. The first is executed when the mouse enters the element(s) concerned, the second when it leaves. So you just need a second callback which undoes the effects of the first one.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Got it working. Thank you for your insight!

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Decoupling Your HTML, CSS, and JavaScript](https://philipwalton.com/articles/decoupling-html-css-and-javascript/).  As it stands there is still no reason not to use classes to solve this incredibly simple problem.

Answer (score 3):

I see you already found your answer, but this is the perfect place for CSS to shine.

CSS:

```
#table-dropdown tr:hover a {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:red;
}
```

[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/73484/)

Comment: This works too but minor quirk when there's content in the `<tr>`, it will style the `<a>` tag as everything within the `<tr>` tag when hovered, in this case, such as hovering over the `<p>` tag will style the `<a>`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Robin for the insightful answer.

Working example:

```
$('#table-dropdown a').hover(function(){ // style multiple elements on hover action
    $(this).closest('tr').find('a').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('a').css('color', 'red');
}, function(){ // hover out
    $(this).closest('tr').find('a').css('text-decoration', 'none');
    $(this).closest('tr').find('a').css('color', 'black');             
});
```

Comment: You might prefer `$(this).closest('tr').find('a').removeAttr('style');` to revert to whatever applied to that element before you applied `style` to it. This will effectively remove the `style` attribute, so if anything else adds inline style to your links, it's not a good idea.

Comment: Definitely check out Ibu's answer (if you're able to use/edit stylesheets in your project)